# Add comments to Webform Submission pages

Tags: 7, hooks, comments, webforms

We use webforms for a variety of purposes such as feedback questionnaires, contact forms and request forms.

For the request forms we would like to attach comments on the submission page. This is so after the form has been submitted the User and admins can communicate on the follow up from the Request.

From what I understand the submissions pages are unique and only viewable to users who submitted them OR admins.

Anyone have any idea how I could attach unique comment forms to these submissions individually so that only the User who submitted the form and the admins can comment? Would this require a module or is this something which can be a theme override in template.php?

Comment: I have seen 'webform-revisions' module, but it solves nothing to me. Have you got that functionality working?

Comment: We ended up using CCK and nodes in the end for our requests. Although I do see a good reason for developing a Module that would allow comments to be attached to submission and would be interested in helping out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a module for this. It doesn't need to be complex though. But you need a place to store the comments and some code to add the form and handle form submissions.

If you wanted to make something a little bit fancy, you could notify users when new comment on submissions are made.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I was thinking it would require a module. What I am struggling to grasp is how to Hook onto the submission page to create the comments..

Comment: For anyone who might want to do the same, http://drupal.org/project/webform_revisions has provided a work around. It is not as clean and easy as just using comments on the submission page but it does the job.



In the mean time I am going to create a Webform Comments module...